# Difference between closures and endomorphisms

Tags: functional-programming

To my understanding, closures and endomorphism are both properties of functions that have the same input and return type. What makes these concepts different? Are these definitions incorrect? If so, how?

Comment: Where did you learn what closures are?

Comment: I'm aware of the other use of the term. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) is the type of closure I'm referring to. The question is about mathematical rather than lexical closures.

Comment: Ah, I guess you should put that link in the question for not confusing most of the computer programmers here :-) Maybe this question also is better asked over at [maths.SE]

Comment: I guess every set with an endomorphism has closure under that operation, but not every closure is a structure-preserving *morphism*.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for your answer @Bergi!